# UITableViewCell inside PageViewController behaving differently

Tags: ios, uitableview, uipageviewcontroller

I put my working tableviewcontroller inside a pageviewcontroller. Now I have to register the cell in the tableview programmatically and the method awakeFromNib is not called for the cell. All properties in my custom cell are not initialized and the app crashes if I try to set content.

Is there anything different when I add a tableviewcontroller in a pageviewcontroller?

```
self.tableView.registerClass(ParticipantCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: ParticipantCell.cellIdentifier)

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let index = self.sections[indexPath.section].index+indexPath.row

    let participant = self.participants[index]

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(ParticipantCell.cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ParticipantCell

   // cell.setParticipantData(participant)


    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating cells programmatically `awakeFromNib` is not called. However you can do your configurations by overriding:

```
init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?)
```

As a suggestion you can have a method like this:

```
override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    setupCell()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    setupCell()
}

func setupCell() {
    // setup your cell here
}
```

Comment: So I have to add every control programmatically? Everything is defined in IB

Comment: changed this behaviour by loading the viewcontroller from the storyboard. now I do'nt need to register the cell and awake from nib gets called. But the properties are still nil

Comment: I would double check that all elements in your storyboard are tied to your class properties, and I would double check that you are only referencing the properties AFTER the cell has been created/drawn (I have made the mistake of referencing elements at the wrong time in the elements' lifecycle before).

For example, if you were referencing an UILabel in a viewController's viewDidLoad method, it would be nil.  Would have to manipulate the label after the nib/storyboard had been created, in viewWillAppear/viewDidAppear.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the Tableviewcontroller was instantiated wrong. I solved it by instantiating it from the storyboard:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Participants", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle())

if let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ParticipantListController") as? ParticipantListController{
...
}
```